# How to Run an ML model with Django on Live server

Tags: python, django, machine-learning

I have a Django project that uses a public ML model("deepset/roberta-base-squad2") to make some predictions. The server receives a request with parameters which trigger a queued function. This function is what makes the predictions. But this works only on my local. Once I push my project to a live server, the model no starts to run but never completes.
I have tried to set up the project using different guides, to avoid my project downloading the ML model every time a request is made, but it doesn't solve it. I don't know what else to do, please. If there's any extra information needed, I can provide.

Here is my setup as it is now:

**views.py**

```
class BotView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = BotSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
            print(serializer.data)
            return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            return Response(data=str(e), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from .tasks import upload_to_ai

class BotSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    questions = serializers.ListField(required=True, write_only=True)
    user_info = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    merchant = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True, write_only=True)
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        # call ai and run async
        upload_to_ai.delay(validated_data['questions'], validated_data['user_info'], validated_data['merchant'], validated_data['user_id'])
        return "successful"
```

**tasks.py**

```
from bot.apps import BotConfig
from model.QA_Model import predict

@shared_task()
def upload_to_ai(questions:list, user_info:str, merchant:str, user_id:int):
    model_predictions = predict(questions, BotConfig.MODEL, user_info)
    print(model_predictions)
    return
```

**apps.py**

```
class BotConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'bot'
    reader = FARMReader(model_name_or_path="deepset/roberta-base-squad2", top_k=3, use_gpu=False)

    #model pipeline
    MODEL = Pipeline()
    MODEL.add_node(component= reader, name="Reader", inputs=["Query"])
```

**QA_models.py**

```
from haystack import Document
import pandas as pd

def predict(query:list, model, context):
    '''
    This function predicts the answer to question passed as query
    Arguments:
    query: This is/are the question you intend to ask
    model: This is the model for the prediction
    context: This is the data from which the model will find it's answers
    '''
    
    result = model.run_batch(queries=query,
                            documents=[Document(content=context)])
    response = convert_to_dict(result['answers'], query)
    return response
```

Every time I send a request, the ML model begins to run as shown in the image but it never goes past 0%.
[image: terminal showing model running]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this. So all the while, I had been running the ML model in a background process using Celery but it worked when I ran it on the main thread. I don't know yet why it wouldn't run in the background process though.